# Transfer in Lisbon on the way to Boston

Tags: air-travel, transit, lisbon

I am traveling back to Boston from Paris, France, with a connecting flight in Lisbon, Portugal. Will I have to go through security or recheck my bags in Lisbon or just when I arrive in Boston?

Comment: What airline is it?

Comment: Assuming it's TAP Portugal and booked on a single ticket: you do not need to collect and recheck your bags. HOWEVER, signage in the airport is pretty bad and last time I accidentally walked out of the secure area while trying to get to my connection and I had to go through security again.

Comment: It is TAP Portugal and is a single ticket as well.  I am normally not a nervous traveler but I am traveling a portion of the trip alone.  My layover in Lisbon is only an hour and 20 minutes.  I'm hoping that will be plenty of time.  My flight is in and out of Terminal 1.  Is passport control located in that terminal?  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Karen The Lisbon airport isn't all that large, so it should be enough time as long as there aren't significant delays. Passport control will be in that terminal, just check the TV monitors for the gate of your next flight and follow the signs. You'll go through passport control and then be in a special part of the airport just for non-Schengen international departures.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have booked a single ticket, you will not have to go through security or recheck your bags in Lisbon. You will, however, go through Schengen exit immigration, where your passport will be stamped out of the Schengen area.

Comment: Of course the stamp bit assumes the OP is travelling on a non-EU passport (not unreasonably).

Comment: @origimbo I assumed since the OP said "back to Boston," though it is of course possible she's an EU national resident in the US. Either way, there will be passport control on the way out, with or without a stamp.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Lisbon Airport website, whose connecting flight page can be found [here](http://www.aeroportolisboa.pt/en/lis/passenger-guide/what-you-need-to-know/connecting-flights), you do not need to go through a security checkpoint when you arrive in Lisbon, only passport control. The same website suggests contacting your airline to make sure your luggage is automatically sent to your final destination.

My hunch is that if you're on a full-service carrier (likely, TAP, I'm guessing), that they'll forward your baggage for you. That's been my experience in Schengen country to non-Schengen country connections elsewhere in Europe.